# Query to exclude an array column in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Below json represents a document structure of my collection.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("591a653c366df19100ed0fbc"),
    "sno" : 1,
    "chapterName" : "chapter 1: Express JS",
    "overView" : "Overview of Express JS",
    "sections" : [
            {
                    "title" : "The Node.js philosophy",
                    "subSections" : [
                            {
                                    "sno" : 1,
                                    "title" : "Small core 1",
                                    "content" : "The Node.js core itself has its foundations 1"
                            },
                            {
                                    "sno" : 2,
                                    "title" : "Small core 2",
                                    "content" : "The Node.js core itself has its foundations 2"
                            }
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "title" : "The Node.js philosophy 2",
                    "subSections" : [
                            {
                                    "sno" : 1,
                                    "title" : "Small core 1",
                                    "content" : "The Node.js core itself has its foundations 1"
                            },
                            {
                                    "sno" : 2,
                                    "title" : "Small core 2",
                                    "content" : "The Node.js core itself has its foundations 2"
                            }
                    ]
            }
    ]
}
```

I would like to write a query which will return data for all records in below mentioned way (excluding "content" )

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("591a653c366df19100ed0fbc"),
    "sno" : 1,
    "chapterName" : "chapter 1: Express JS",
    "overView" : "Overview of Express JS",
    "sections" : [
            {
                    "title" : "The Node.js philosophy",
                    "subSections" : [
                            {
                                    "sno" : 1,
                                    "title" : "Small core 1"

                            },
                            {
                                    "sno" : 2,
                                    "title" : "Small core 2"

                            }
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "title" : "The Node.js philosophy 2",
                    "subSections" : [
                            {
                                    "sno" : 1,
                                    "title" : "Small core 1"

                            },
                            {
                                    "sno" : 2,
                                    "title" : "Small core 2"

                            }
                    ]
            }
    ]
}
```

Any idea how to achive that ?

Comment: It's possible. But you really should not be nesting arrays as there are limitations on how that can be updated. So while possible, it's also not trivial, and would be much simpler and performant if you flattened the document structure a bit. Think attributes on items in a single array rather than nesting one array within another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So do-able but "not trivial". This requires heavy use of [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) with `.aggregate()`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
      "sno": 1,
      "chapterName": 1,
      "overView": 1,
      "sections": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$sections",
          "as": "section",
          "in": {
            "title": "$$section.title",
            "subSections": {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$$section.subSections",
                "as": "subSection",
                "in": {
                  "sno": "$$subSection.sno",
                  "title": "$$subSection.title"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }}
])
```

I just want to make a mention about "flattening" though, and outside of all the other considerations of why not to have nested arrays, simply consider this data:

```js
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5921745d13fbc408ee20a60a"),
  "a" : 1, 
  "b" : [
    { "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3 }, 
    { "a" : 4, "b" : 5, "c" : 6 }
  ]
}
```

Since that's only one array level deep, if I want to exclude the `"c"` property then all I need do is:

```js
db.collection.find({},{ "b.c": 0 })
```

And I get of course:

```js
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5921745d13fbc408ee20a60a"),
  "a" : 1, 
  "b" : [
    { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }, 
    { "a" : 4, "b" : 5 }
  ]
}
```

And that's clearly a lot simpler than nesting `$map` statements in an aggregate projection.

Food for thought.